# d8 webform submission views how to exclude Action Apply to Selected Items

Tags: views, 8, webforms

The view created using the webform views integration module.. all the fields are shown as desired.  However the CBO box with choices to then apply changes is not wanted. Hoping it's a setting somewhere.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just after posting I found the answer.  In fields section, the webform submissions bulk operation form entry can be deleted and that removes the pesky entry shown in the question.